# Listbox Component with advanced formatting options?

Tags: delphi, listbox, components, delphi-xe

I am looking for a listbox style component that offers advanced text formatting options.

I know you can ownerdraw regular listboxes using the OnDrawItem procedure, but for the requirements I need I think it would be better to use a control that may already offer what I am looking for.

Look at this sample screenshot:

[image]

`Word Styling` - Allow individual characters/words to be styled differently.

`Text Links` - certain items entered into the listbox could be recognised as a link (not necessarily a url link though). In this example brown fox is marked as link, when the mouse moves over the brown fox text the font becomes underlined. Selecting this could do anything such as show a message, open a form etc.

Note, when a list item is selected the font styles should remain the same. Additionally if the listbox could support images (especially several images in a row) that would be a bonus.

I was thinking a HTML listbox or similar could be just what I need. That would allow inputting the items into the listbox like as code with tags for example.

Could anyone recommend a component that offers this type of capabilities?

Thanks.

Comment: The [`TJvHTListBox`](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help:TJvHTListBox) from [`JEDI Visual Component Library`](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/) is a list box control that allows to use HTML formatting for the items, however it doesn't render the items correctly at item hovering and except that would be needed to implement image tag parsing and modify drawing method for their rendering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [THTMListbox](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/htmlistb.asp) by TMS Software can do all of this. It can support images and even animated gifs.

It is not free though and is actually part of a bundle (HTML Controls Pack). I think it is well worth looking at though and the support is second to none + you receive full source code.

Comment: Looks promising, I think I will download the trial sometime and see how it well works..

Comment: This component is good but still not perfect for my needs, plus it means buying a full HTML pack which is too much for one component.